# How to properly decode a deflate compressed string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, decode, deflate

I want to decode a string that I have as

```
content-encoding: deflate
```

It is deflate only, it does not have any other compression algorithm.

[image: header data]

```
x?uO?
?0►??§!g§?↨¶?ho??6]?@6←??P??,?¶??????♂?=?♦??►?h☼????,?R☻$??◄???K?|J???n>;??!??c?*?♣6CM???`????#♂z?0???m?O4K?◄????-??z??}?S?M?♣?l?Q/????uo??dq
```

I have tried several decoding algorithms, with the gzip for example, but it gives me an error, something about the wrong header, also with the base64 ones and it says it is wrong. I have tried with several decoders but I don't get it.

These are the values it should have once decoded.

[image]

This stack was passed on to me, but it didn't help either
[Deflate string C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850830/deflate-string-c-sharp).

Please help.

Decode a "string content-encoding: deflate" to obtain the response value. In C#.

Comment: If your data is a string and has those question marks, data is irrevocably lost. Try again, but now from the source _bytes_. How did you obtain the data? Is this a response to an HTTP request you make from code?

Comment: Yes. is a HttpClient{BaseAddress = new Uri()

Comment: You men something like this?  
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate };
                var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(IONAPIBaseUrl) };